# Resource index parameters

Tags: php, controller, laravel-5.1

I've wrote a controller to have it's `index` to output the `DataTables` plugin data.

A excerpt:

```
public function index() {
    return Datatable::collection(\App\Slip::where('paid', '=', false)->get())
        ...
        ->make();
}
```

and the route:

```
Route::resource('api/slip', 'SlipsController');
```

everything works fine, the problem is that this `index` return only items with `paid = false` that's right for one view, but for the other view I need all items/rows.

so what's the best practice to make `index` function cover both cases (all and those with `paid = false`)?

A post param is the first thing that comes to my mind, but the data is loaded by the `DataTables` plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not?. You need detect your specified view and send some extra param in ajax-request. Like:

```
 $('...').DataTable({
      ....
      "ajax": {
            'type': 'GET',
            'url': "....",
            'data': {paid: false},

      },
      ....
 });
```

Now in action:

```
public function index(Request $request) {
  $paid = $request->input('paid');      
  $items = [];
  if ($paid){
    $items = \App\Slip::all()->get();
  }else{
    $items = \App\Slip::where('paid', '=', false)->get();
  }           

  return Datatable::collection($items)
    ...
    ->make();
}
```